# ASP.NET Core Error while using Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, db-first

I have Visual Studio 2015 and using ASP.NET Core Web API.

I am creating application using database first approach, for that I am using following command in nuget package manager console,

```
Scaffold-DbContext
    -Connection "'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyERP;Trusted_Connection=True;'"
    -Provider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" -OutputDir "DBModels"
    -Context "ApplicationDbContext"
```

After firing this command I am getting following error:

> Startup project 'src\Ang2CoreApi' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core
>   project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of
>   projects.

Comment: HI @Akash, I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution to the error?

Comment: Also same issue: VS 2015 and Core Web app .Net Framework.

Comment: Yes I solved that issue, Please follows the procedures as it is shown on the answer section of this question

Answer (score 0):

First add ASP.NET CORE 1.1.1 runtime and verify that it is installed on the following location

C:/Program files/dotnet/1.1.1 
On the above locaion there should be folder named 1.1.1

Then change project.json

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {

    "version": "1.1.1",

      "type": "platform"

    }
```

Then after go to your project folder and open cmd there 
Then fire following command

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models/DbEntities

It will create DbEntities folder under Models folder